Capturing video stream from raspberry pi on a laptop
Goal:
I am part of a college engineering club building an ROV submersible. We're using a Raspberry Pi 3B running vanilla Raspberry Pi OS to process the video feed. The Pi will be tethered to a surface laptop via an Ethernet (Cat 6e) cable. I have a cheap Amazon USB webcam that works on the Pi (confirmed by saving pictures and videos reliably). I'm trying to set up a stream of the webcam video feed but am running into errors.
Setup:
Network Configuration:

Laptop IP: xxx.xxx.x.1
Pi IP: xxx.xxx.x.2
Firewall: Disabled on the laptop
Cable: Tested and working for both devices (not connected to an
actual network during operation)

What I Tried:
Initial Command:
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -video_size 1920x1080 -i /dev/video0 -f mpegts udp://xxx.xxx.x.1:1234
On the Pi, the stream seems to start (camera LED turns on).
On the laptop, VLC is launched with udp://xxx.xxx.x.1:1234.
VLC Behavior:
VLC loads for a few seconds, starts counting the timestamp, but only shows a black screen with the VLC logo.
The advanced debugger in VLC shows errors related to dropped/missing packets or mangled data.
Variations Tried:
Different VLC URLs: udp://xxx.xxx.x.1@:1234, udp://@:1234
Other protocols: RTP, HTTP
Modifying ffmpeg settings: Using libx264, flv
Error Examples:
Errors in VLC differ depending on the command used on the Pi. Common issues include dropped packets or incorrect data format.
What I Need:
Any of the following would help me solve this issue.

Adjustment for VLC (or laptop) settings to properly receive the stream.
Configuration for a UDP command that works for this setup.
A different streaming protocol which would be more suitable for this use case.
An alternative solution to display the video feed from the Raspberry Pi on the laptop over Ethernet.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

Paranoia! Why obscure presumably private IP addresses?

Have you tested your web cam independently?

@Milliways I have posted this on behalf of the school (which also owns all of the hardware) and they requested I do not reveal information about the school when I asked for permission to post this. I believe that the IP it self should not impact any answers so I left it blank in an abundance of caution.

@liaifat85 Yes. I have tested the camera on multiple devices including Windows devices and the PI itself. When setting recording video directly to the PIs storage it works perfectly, and it appears to work when the stream starts (a status LED turns on).
